# Difference between EGit Username/Password and git user.name/user.email?

Tags: git, authentication, github, egit, git-config

I created a private repository on GitHub, and added a `README` so that my repo can "be cloned immediately" (GitHub verbiage). Then, in Eclipse/EGit, I:

1. `Import >> Projects from Git`
2. Select `URI`
3. Now, in the `Import Projects from Git` dialog, I see a `Username` and `Password` field at the bottom.

Several questions here:

1. I assume that the `Username` and `Password` fields are my GitHub account credentials, yes?
2. How do these credentials differ from the `user.name` and `user.email` properties that I can configure in my `USER_HOME/.gitconfig` file (or for a single repo, my `.git/config` file)?
3. Just out of curiosity, why do I need to add a `README` to my repo at creation-time, in order to make my repo "immediately cloneable", as GitHub states? If I didn't do this, what extra steps would I need to do to clone it?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that the Username and Password fields are my GitHub account credentials, yes?

Yes, if you want to push back to GitHub and still be views as your GitHub account, you should push commits done with the username and email of your GitHub account (as explained in this [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git)).

> How do these credentials differ from the user.name and user.email properties that I can configure in my `USER_HOME/.gitconfig` file (or for a single repo, my .git/config file)?

It doesn't differ, in that EGit would update the local config (`repo/.git/config`).
The git settings considered by EGit are the concatenation of:

- local config first (`repo/.git/config`)
- global config second (`%USER_HOME%/.gitconfig`)
- system config third (`/path/to/git/etc/config`)

> why do I need to add a `README` to my repo at creation-time

This is more a GitHub convention, for your project to have a readable description, for others to see.